# Match items in nested a dictionary and return outer-key

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, nested, match

Hi I am trying to write some code that compares several nested dictionaries for a match of a specific item, which if true returns the outer key.

I have tried using nested for loops and a list of the dictionary names to sort and find matches, the code first grabs individual dictionaries dict1 and dict2 then compares the ['ID'] key inside each dictionary for a match See Below:

```
Dictionary1 = {'key1':{'ID':'ID1'}, 'key2':{'ID':'ID2'}, 'key3':{'ID':'ID3'}}

Dictionary2 = {'key4':{'ID':'ID1'}, 'key5':{'ID':'ID2'}, 'key6':{'ID':'ID3'}}



DictionaryList = [Dictionary1, Dictionary2]


for Dict1 in DictionaryList:
    for Dict2 in DictionaryList:
        for Key1 in Dict1:
            for Key2 in Dict2:
                if Dict1[Key1]['ID'] == Dict2[Key2]['ID']:
                    print('Dictionary1' + ': ' + Key1 + ' // ' 'Dictionary2' + ': ' + Key2)
```

This code returns 12 matches and their outer keys, most of which are wrong, see below:

```
Dictionary1: key1 // Dictionary2: key1
Dictionary1: key2 // Dictionary2: key2
Dictionary1: key3 // Dictionary2: key3
Dictionary1: key1 // Dictionary2: key4
Dictionary1: key2 // Dictionary2: key5
Dictionary1: key3 // Dictionary2: key6
Dictionary1: key4 // Dictionary2: key1
Dictionary1: key5 // Dictionary2: key2
Dictionary1: key6 // Dictionary2: key3
Dictionary1: key4 // Dictionary2: key4
Dictionary1: key5 // Dictionary2: key5
Dictionary1: key6 // Dictionary2: key6
```

I suspect this is because the dictionaries are being matched against themselves and each other several times, ie the code compares Dictionary1 to Dictionary1 then Dictionary2 to Dictionary2 and so on.

The expected result would be the code to print 3 matches:

```
Dictionary1: key1 // Dictionary2: key4
Dictionary1: key2 // Dictionary2: key5
Dictionary1: key3 // Dictionary2: key6
```

I am new to python/programming so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry I should clarify although in my example there are only two dictionaries in my actual problem I am trying to match items in 12 individual dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you have combined the dictionaries into a list then tried to iterate over that. You could have simply used the dictionaries themselves:

```
for Key1 in Dictionary1:
    for Key2 in Dictionary2:
        if Dictionary1[Key1]['ID'] == Dictionary2[Key2]['ID']:
            print('Dictionary1' + ': ' + Key1 + ' // ' 'Dictionary2' + ': ' + Key2)
```

This will print

```
Dictionary1: key1 // Dictionary2: key4
Dictionary1: key2 // Dictionary2: key5
Dictionary1: key3 // Dictionary2: key6
```

Comment: Hi, I actually have 12 dictionaries I want to match items in, I only used two as an example. So I thought creating a list and iterating over it would be easier than writing out for key1 in Dictionary 1 through 12 for key2 in Dictionary1 through 12.

Comment: In this case use `itertools.combinations()` to generate all possible 2-dictionary combinations.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a reverse mapping dict that maps the IDs in `Dictionary2` to their keys, so that you can achieve the desired output in linear time by iterating through `Dictionary1` and map each ID to the corresponding key in `Dictionary2` via the reverse mapping dict:

```
mapping = {d['ID']: k for k, d in Dictionary2.items()}
for k, d in Dictionary1.items():
    print('Dictionary1' + ': ' + k + ' // ' 'Dictionary2' + ': ' + mapping[d['ID']])
```

This outputs:

```
Dictionary1: key1 // Dictionary2: key4
Dictionary1: key2 // Dictionary2: key5
Dictionary1: key3 // Dictionary2: key6
```